# i am not getting any idea that where is error occured node js callback not function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback

in this function we get id from Mongo Database and process function to put varriable in GetID varriable
"callback is not function"

```
  var GetID = function( nameval , callback ){
  console.log(nameval);
  console.log("munesh hello");
  var result = GenerateID.find({ "id_name" : nameval },{"id_code":1 , "id_value":1 , "_id":0},function( err , genvalue ) {
    if ( err )
    {
        console.log('error has been occured');
        //throw err;
    }
    else {
        if(genvalue === null)
        {
            callback( err , false );
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(genvalue);
            //calling this function
            callback( err , true );
        }
    }
    //        console.log(genvalue);
     });
     console.log('munesh kumar');
     //  console.log(result);
     console.log('kumar'); 
    };
```

Comment: events.js:160 
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at D:\mean_project\app\routes\generate_id.js:101:17
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\mean_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3419:16)
    at D:\mean_project\node_modules\kareem\index.js:264:21
    at D:\mean_project\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: You can edit the question and add the error message over there

Comment: Also, can you show us how you are calling `GetID`?

Comment: what you need to know

Comment: var region_id = GenerateID.GetID( name );

Comment: What are the parameters you are passing to it?

Comment: from another js file

Comment: So you see the problem? You are sending `name` as parameter. But you are not sending the second parameter (`callback`)

Comment: name = "Region"

Comment: will you clear it

Comment: output of Calling main function                  { region_name: 'EAST ASIA',
  status: true,
  cretaed_by: 'munesh',
  _id: 58aadedbd4161f00983d31c7,
  created_date: 2017-02-20T12:19:39.877Z }                         but according to asynchronus call the data i need is below
[ { id_code: 'RE', id_value: 1 } ]

Answer (score 0):

When calling `GetID`, you are not sending 2 parameters (`nameval` and `callback`). You are only sending the first parameter:

```
var region_id = GenerateID.GetID( name );
```

Instead this is how you should call the function:

```
GenerateID.GetID(name, function(error, result) {

  if(error) {
    // handle error

  } else {

    if(!result) {
      // not found
    } else {
      // do something with result
    }
  }
});
```

Remember that you are dealing with asynchronous functions. You cannot `return` output directly from an asynchronous function (`GetID`). Instead you have to pass it to the callback function.

Your `GetID` function should be something like this:

```
var GetID = function(nameval, callback) {

  GenerateID
    .find({ "id_name": nameval }, { "id_code": 1, "id_value": 1, "_id": 0 }, function(err, genvalue) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        if (genvalue === null) {
          callback(null, null); // no document found
        } else {
          callback(null, genvalue);
        }
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: var region_id = GenerateID.GetID( name , function(error, result) {
  if(error) {
console.log("getting any error");
 } else {
  if(result === null) {
  console.log('data is not coming');
  callback( err , false );
  } else {
   console.log('data is coming');
  callback( err , true );
   }
  }
 });
  console.log(region_id);
console.log("Data is coming");

Comment: Kindly don't paste code into the comments. No one can understand it

Answer (score 0):

```
 var region_id = GenerateID.GetID( name , function(error, result) {
                        if(error) {
                            // handle error
                        console.log("getting any error");
                        } else {
                            console.log(region_id);
                            if(!result) {
                                console.log('data is not coming');

                            } else {
                                console.log('data is coming');

                            }
                        }
                    });



 get id function are below                                              var GetID =function( nameval ,callback){
console.log(nameval);
console.log("munesh hello");

   GenerateID.find({ "id_name" : nameval },{"id_code":1 , "id_value":1 , "_id":0},function( err , genvalue ) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('hello');
       // callback(err);
    } else {
        if (genvalue === null) {
            console.log('123');
            callback(null, null); // no document found
        } else {
            console.log('456');
            callback(null, genvalue);
        }
    }
  });

  };
```

Comment: i am not getting any data it will display "undefined"       REGION
munesh hello
undefined
Data is coming
{ region_name: 'EAST ASIA',
  status: true,
  cretaed_by: 'munesh',
  _id: 58aae3bd68636a1704dd8ea0,
  created_date: 2017-02-20T12:40:29.120Z }
[ { id_code: 'RE', id_value: 1 } ]
munesh hello Kumar